# Update existing mysql record using php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Trying to update existing records in phpMyAdmin, but the following code doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php 
$id = stripslashes($_POST['id']);

$title = stripslashes($_POST['title']);
$first = stripslashes($_POST['first']);
$surname = stripslashes($_POST['surname']);
$email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$promotion = stripslashes($_POST['promotion']);

$maths11 = stripslashes($_POST['maths11']);
$english11 = stripslashes($_POST['english11']);
$english13 = stripslashes($_POST['english13']);
$science13 = stripslashes($_POST['science13']);
$maths133 = stripslashes($_POST['maths133']);
$maths132 = stripslashes($_POST['maths132']);

$address = stripslashes($_POST['address']);
$address2 = stripslashes($_POST['address2']);
$town = stripslashes($_POST['town']);
$county = stripslashes($_POST['county']);
$code = stripslashes($_POST['code']);
$tel = stripslashes($_POST['tel']);

//database connection

$query="UPDATE Promotions SET address='$address', address2='$address2', town='$town', county='$county', postcode='$code', tel='$tel' WHERE id = '$id'";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


include 'confirm.php';
include 'registerEmail.php';
?>
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Please check it you have entered `county` instead of `country` or there must be something wrong in your column names or table name.

Comment: Try outputting mysql_error(), that should give you a pretty detailed description of what went wrong.

Comment: try this: mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); and post results

Comment: Sorry Matt but I tried your code just as written even the mysql table is ditto and still I'm getting updated on running it, I didn't find any error in your mysql query. There must be something else please check you code once again or give us the whole code.

Comment: I think you are not able to connect to the mysql database. Please check it Matt.

Comment: Full code now. Anything? I still cant work it out

Comment: `foreach($_POST as & $val) $val = stripslashes($val);` - help to simplify your code :) And you should escape your data

Answer (score 4):

Instead of rather useless `die ('Error updating database');` handle your errors in more informative way

```
mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().' in '.$query);
```

and read what it says

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_error()` like Col. Shrapnel showed.

But what troubles me ... Is that all the code for that page? Because you have `//database connection` but I don't see any database connection. Are you sure you are connecting to your database and included that connection in your file?

EDIT:

what does your query look like when you echo it? maybe the id is empty ... that way you can see what exactly is going to be send to the db

```
echo $query;
```

Comment: Yeah I connected to the database, just didn't put it up on here

Comment: maybe you should post how your db table promotions looks like. That might help as well. ps: I edited my question.